# WebpackError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined, with gatsby and netlify

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

Everything works on development, but when I go to production I get an error of:
 `WebpackError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined`

But when I `console.log(this.props);` `location: {pathname: "/", ...}` shows up as one of the key value pairs.

This is in my `index.js` for layouts.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'components/head';
import Header from 'components/header';
import Footer from 'components/footer';
import PageIsLoading from 'gatsby-page-is-loading';
import PageProgress from 'components/page-progress';
import NoSSR from 'react-no-ssr';

export default class Template extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      madeInUSA,
      freeShipping,
      eaton,
      cornerstone,
      ingot,
      tailgater,
      creditCards,
      comodoSecure
    } = this.props.data;
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="layout-container">
        <Head />
        <Header
          homePage={this.props.location.pathname === '/' ? true : false}
          topImage={madeInUSA}
          freeImage={freeShipping}
          homeBoxImages={[ingot, eaton, tailgater, cornerstone]}
        />
        {this.props.children()}
        <Footer footerImages={{ creditCards, comodoSecure }} />
        <NoSSR>
          <PageIsLoading>
            <PageProgress />
          </PageIsLoading>
        </NoSSR>
        <style jsx>{``}</style>
        <style jsx global>{`
          html {
            height: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
          }
          *,
          *:before,
          *:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
          }
          h1,
          h2,
          h3,
          h4,
          h5,
          h6 {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica,
              Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            color: #222;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
            margin-top: 0.2rem;
            margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
            line-height: 1.4;
          }
          body {
            position: relative;
            min-height: 100%;
            margin: 0;

            font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica,
              Arial, sans-serif;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
          }
          html,
          body {
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
          }
          img {
            max-width: 100%;
          }
          ::selection {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
          }

          .layout-container {
            padding: 0px 18px;
          }

          hr {
            border: solid #ddd;
            border-width: 1px 0 0;
            height: 0;
            margin: 10px 0;
          }

          p {
            font-family: inherit;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 1rem;
            line-height: 1.6;
            margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
          }

          @media (min-width: 1100px) {
            .layout-container {
              max-width: 1100px;
              min-height: 100vh;
              margin: 0 auto;
              background: #fff;
            }

            body {
              background: #e5eaee;
            }
          }
        `}</style>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query HeaderQueries {
    madeInUSA: imageSharp(id: { regex: "/made-in-usa.png/" }) {
      sizes(maxWidth: 162) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes_noBase64
      }
    }
    freeShipping: imageSharp(id: { regex: "/free-shipping/" }) {
      sizes(maxWidth: 1100) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes_noBase64
      }
    }
    ingot: imageSharp(id: { regex: "/ingot.png/" }) {
      sizes(maxWidth: 195) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes_noBase64
      }
    }
    eaton: imageSharp(id: { regex: "/eaton.png/" }) {
      sizes(maxWidth: 195) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes_noBase64
      }
    }
    cornerstone: imageSharp(id: { regex: "/cornerstone.png/" }) {
      sizes(maxWidth: 195) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes_noBase64
      }
    }
    tailgater: imageSharp(id: { regex: "/tailgater.png/" }) {
      sizes(maxWidth: 195) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes_noBase64
      }
    }
    creditCards: imageSharp(id: { regex: "/credit-cards.jpg/" }) {
      sizes(maxWidth: 525) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes_noBase64
      }
    }
    comodoSecure: imageSharp(id: { regex: "/comodo_secure.png/" }) {
      sizes(maxWidth: 100) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes_noBase64
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set default props for the location before you do `gatsby build`

Example:

```
layout.defaultProps = {
  location: {},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In v1, the layout component had access to history, location, and match props. In v2, only pages have access to these props. If you need these props in the layout component, pass them through from the page.

For more information, check the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/migrating-from-v1-to-v2/#4-pass-history-location-and-match-props-to-layout).